# How to change Python menu bar app logo black and white based on Mac menu bar light or dark?

Tags: python, macos, menubar, rumps

I want to make a Python menu bar application using the `rumps` package, but I want to make my menu bar logo change from black and white based on the Mac menu bar color, is there any way to accomplish this using `rumps`? Or if there isn't a way is it possible to do it through another Python package?

MacOS: 12.0.1
Python: 3.9.8

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a package that can read/register macOS theme changes dynamically, but you can query the active theme directly using `defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle`:

```py
import subprocess

command = "defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle"
result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

if result.stdout.rstrip() == "Dark":
    # Dark Mode
else:
    # Light Mode
```

This approach assumes your client has the appropriate permissions to access system information and run system commands.